# Thread-safe strtok in C

Tags: c, strings, parsing

(This post has a [version II](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289602/thread-safe-strtok-in-c-version-ii).)

Since `strtok` is not thread-safe, I decided to practice and write a thread-safe replacement. This code and the demo runner may be found [at GitHub](https://github.com/coderodde/ThreadSafeStrtok.c).

## Code

**`com_github_coderodde_thread_safe_strtok.h:`**

```
#ifndef COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_THREAD_SAFE_STRTOK_H
#define COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_THREAD_SAFE_STRTOK_H

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct string_token {
    const char* token;
    struct string_token* next_string_token;
} string_token;

typedef struct string_token_data {
    struct string_token* head_string_token;
    size_t number_of_tokens;
} string_token_data;

string_token_data* string_tokenize(const char* const text, 
                                   const char* const delimiters);

const char** 
convert_string_token_data_to_string_array(string_token_data* data);

#endif
```

**`com_github_coderodde_thread_safe_strtok.c:`**

```
#include "com_github_coderodde_thread_safe_strtok.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/********************************************************************
* Returns 'true' iff 'ch' is mentioned in the delimiter characters. *
********************************************************************/
static bool character_belongs_to_delimiter_set(
                char ch,
                const char* const delimiters) {

    char* current_char_ptr = delimiters;

    while (current_char_ptr != NULL) {
        if (*current_char_ptr == '\0') {
            return false;
        }

        if (*current_char_ptr == ch) {
            return true;
        }

        current_char_ptr++;
    }

    return false;
}

static void string_token_init(string_token* st,
                              const char* const token,
                              const string_token* const next_string_token) {
    st->token = token;
    st->next_string_token = next_string_token;
}

static string_token* string_token_alloc(
            const char* const token,
            const string_token* const next_string_token) {

    string_token* st = malloc(sizeof(st));

    if (st == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    string_token_init(st, token, next_string_token);

    return st;
}

static const char* string_token_copy(const char* const text, 
                                     size_t token_offset,
                                     size_t token_length) {

    /* + 1 in order to malloc the space for zero-terminator: */
    char* token_text = malloc(sizeof(char) * (token_length + 1));

    /* Terminate the token: */
    token_text[token_length] = '\0';

    /* Copy text[token_offset], ..., text[token_offset + token_length - 1]: */
    strncpy_s(token_text, 
              token_length + 1, 
              &text[token_offset], 
              token_length);

    return token_text;
}

string_token_data* string_tokenize(const char* const text,
                              const char* const delimiters) {
    if (text == NULL || delimiters == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    string_token_data* data = malloc(sizeof(*data));

    if (data == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    string_token* head_string_token = NULL;
    string_token* tail_string_token = NULL;

    size_t text_length = strlen(text);
    size_t previous_token_start_index = 0;
    size_t number_of_tokens = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < text_length + 1; i++) {
        char ch = text[i];

        if (character_belongs_to_delimiter_set(ch, delimiters) || ch == '\0') {
            size_t token_length = i - previous_token_start_index;

            const char* token_text = 
                string_token_copy(text,
                                  previous_token_start_index, 
                                  token_length);

            string_token* st = string_token_alloc(token_text, NULL);

            if (head_string_token == NULL) {
                head_string_token = st;
                tail_string_token = st;
            } else {
                tail_string_token->next_string_token = st;
                tail_string_token = st;
            }

            if (token_length == 0) {
                previous_token_start_index = i + 1;
            } else {
                previous_token_start_index = i + 1;
            }

            number_of_tokens++;
        }
    }

    data->head_string_token = head_string_token;
    data->number_of_tokens = number_of_tokens;

    return data;
}

const char**
convert_string_token_data_to_string_array(string_token_data* data) {
    const char * *const arr = malloc(data->number_of_tokens);
    string_token* st = data->head_string_token;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < data->number_of_tokens; i++) {

        size_t token_length = strlen(st->token) + 1;
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * token_length);

        strncpy_s(arr[i],
            token_length,
            st->token,
            token_length);

        st = st->next_string_token;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

The above implementation supports empty tokens too.

## Critique request

As always, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: You do know, do you not, that POSIX already defines (and some non-POSIX implementations also provide, I think) function [`strtok_r()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3p.html), a reentrant version of `strtok()`?  That doesn't necessarily mean that you shouldn't write your own tokenizer, but if you're going to call it "a thread-safe version of the same function" then you should consider how POSIX thinks such a thing should look and act.

Comment: To emphasize what @JohnBollinger, `strtok()` _can't_ be implemented in a thread-safe manner (otherwise it would have been). It requires something to hold the context, which necessarily means adding a parameter and having a different API, hence `strok_r()`.

Answer (score 8):

- Since this is not a drop-in replacement of `strtok`, which iterates token, but only allows a complete tokenization of a string, I'd not expose `string_tokenize` at all. The client doesn't need to know anything about `struct string_token` nor `struct string_token_data`. An interface returning an array of strings feels more natural.
- Freeing the memory owned by `struct string_token_data` is sorely missing.
- `character_belongs_to_delimiter_set` - any reason to not use `strchr`? Along the same line, instead of manually testing each character for being a delimiter, consider calling `strpbrk`.
- `sizeof(char)` by definition equals to 1. On the other hand,

  ```
    const char * *const arr = malloc(data->number_of_tokens);
  ```

  is missing a `sizeof(char *)` factor.
- Declare variables as close to their use as possible. In `string_tokenize`, `data` is is declared confusingly early. As a side note, a dynamic allocation of `data` is not necessary at all. Consider returning `string_token_data` structure rather than a pointer.
- I didn't check correctness, but

  ```
        if (token_length == 0) {
            previous_token_start_index = i + 1;
        } else {
            previous_token_start_index = i + 1;
        }
  ```

  looks strange.
- `tail_string_token = st;` shall be lifted out of `if/else` clause.

Comment: All very good points. I shall reiterate in a nearby future.

Comment: One would not use `strchr()` because it does not well serve the case where there are multiple delimiter characters.  But `strcspn()`, on the other hand, is just the ticket.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Perhaps I was too vague. The comment meant that `strchr(delimiters, ch)` is exactly what `character_belongs_to_delimiter_set` is doing.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Fair enough.  As I wrote in my answer, though, I would recommend getting rid of `character_belongs_to_delimiter_set` altogether -- which can be done pretty easily by use of `strcspn()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger and vnp: there are reasons to roll your own `strpbrk` / `strcspn`: you're making multiple calls with the same delimiter set, so you only need to construct the array of `bool` once (assuming you use the implementation technique that normal libc functions use, of building a 256-entry LUT).  If you want it to go faster on x86, for many delimiter lists you can build a set of chars or ranges for SSE4.2 `pcmpistri` that lets you check 16 chars at once and get a first-match position.  Or when the delimiter list has length 1, `strchr` (x86 `pcmpeqb` against `_mm_set1_epi8(*delim)`)

Comment: That may well be, @PeterCordes, but the OP's code under review is not an example.

Answer (score 8):

### Significant semantic differences from `strtok()`

> I decided to practice and write a thread-safe version of the same function.

Yours ***is not*** "a thread-safe version of the same function".  Significant differences include:

- `strtok()` provides one token at a time, not all at once.  Among other things, that permits
- `strtok()` allows you to change delimiters between calls while tokenizing the same one string.  Furthermore,
- `strtok()` can and will parse a run of multiple delimiter characters as a single delimiter.  *This is desirable in some cases*, albeit not so much in others.  Your tokenizer does not do this.
- `strtok()` has O(1) memory overhead, whereas your tokenizer has O(N) overhead, because
- `strtok()` does not perform any memory allocation, whereas your tokenizer does.  In particular

  - your tokenizer creates a copy of each token, which is comparatively slow, and places a burden on the caller to manage that allocated memory.
- On the plus side, your function can tokenize unmodifiable input strings, because
- your tokenizer does not modify its input.  Also,
- your tokenizer can and will parse empty tokens.  This is desirable in some cases, albeit not so much in others.

Compare to POSIX's [`strtok_r()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3p.html) for a function that is much better described as a thread-safe version of `strtok()`.  It is not a drop-in replacement because it requires an extra parameter, but it is much closer to one than your tokenizer is.  Existing code can be converted very easily from `strtok()` to `strtok_r()`.

### Naming issues

Call your source files whatever you like, but **I dislike the comically long name of your header**, which clients of your tokenizer will need to use in their own sources.  C is not Java.  Choose something shorter, such as `coderodde_tokenizer.h`

**I would also shorten the name of `convert_string_token_data_to_string_array()`**.  Who wants to type that?  Who wants to read it?  Something like `string_token_data_to_array` is shorter and just as descriptive, for example.

And in your public structures, **prefer conventional names for your head and next pointers** (`head` and `next`).  Including the name of the pointed to type  in these names adds nothing useful yet increases cognitive load, especially because it is unconventional.

**The name of `string_token_alloc()` is misleading** because this function does not just allocate, but also initializes (even if by calling another function).  I'd probably use the word "create" instead of "alloc" in the name.

### `const` craziness

**There is no good reason to declare your tokens `const`**.  They are definitely modifiable, or at least would be if you did not gratuitously declare them `const`.  Surely it is reasonable and appropriate to let the client program decide whether to modify them.  Moreover, the client is responsible for freeing these objects, and the `const`-qualification interferes with that: to satisfy language constraints, the client must cast away the `const` qualifiers to free the tokens.

**The `next_string_token` parameters to functions `string_token_init` and `string_token_alloc` should be declared as pointers to *non*-`const` objects**, because that is what is what matches the type of the structure member to which that value is eventually assigned.  With these being declared as pointers to `const` data, the constness needs to be cast away for the ultimate assignment to satisfy C language constraints.

**There is little value to declaring function parameters `const`** (as opposed to declaring them as pointers to `const` data, which is a different thing).  Are you really so concerned that you might accidentally modify one inside the function that you need to ensure that the compiler rejects attempts to do so?  You seem to be doing that for parameters of pointer type but not for parameters of other types, but remember that in C, *all* arguments are passed by value.  Declaring the parameters `const` is not needed to prevent the arguments presented by the caller (themselves) being modified by the function, and it is not effective for preventing the data to which any of them point being modified by the function.

### Other design considerations

As a matter of code style, **I personally dislike most uses of `typedef`**.  I would rather see you just use your structures' natural names, `struct string_token` and `struct string_token_data`, and dispense with the typedefs.  Especially so since the definitions of these structure types need to be visible to client code anyway.

**It would be a convenience to users if `convert_string_token_data_to_string_array()` returned an array with a null pointer marking the end**.

It is reasonable for `string_tokenize()` to return a null pointer when the input string is null, though `strtok()` itself simply insists that the input string *not* be null.  On the other hand, **there are better behaviors available for a null delimiter string**.  For example,

- treat that the same as an empty delimiter string, which results in the whole input being parsed as a single token; or
- provide a default set of delimiters, perhaps something like `" \t"`.

**Consider having `string_tokenize()` return a `struct string_token_data` by value** instead of returning a pointer to a dynamically allocated one.  The structure is small, and avoiding the dynamic allocation and consequent requirement to free could be useful.

**Consider providing a function to free the linked list inside a `struct string_token_data`**.    It's rude to leave the user with the choice of either writing their own code for that or leaking the memory.  It's a bit complicated by the question of whether to free only the nodes or also the tokens, but you could provide a parameter to control that.

### Implementation details

**Use the standard `strcspn()` function** to find delimiter characters in the input.  In addition to allowing you to dump the entire (then-)needless `character_belongs_to_delimiter_set()` function, it will give you token lengths directly.

**Do not use `strncpy_s()`**.  Only one major C implementation supports it and the other `*_s` functions, and its implementations of these diverge from the specifications of these functions in the language spec's optional Annex K.  It's not doing anything useful for you anyway, because you already know at the points of call that the buffer you are copying into is large enough.

If you don't want `string_token_copy()` to trust the passed-in token length then that's fine, but in that case, **don't use `strncpy()` either**.  That serves a few rather narrow special-purposes, and in particular, it does not guarantee to null terminate.  Instead, for your particular purposes, set the first byte of the destination to 0 and use `strncat()`.  Among the benefits is that you then don't need to manually terminate the result.

**`string_token_copy()` does not verify that its `malloc` call succeeds.**

The **`string_token_init`** function has a two-line body and is called in only one place.  Splitting it out as a separate function seems superfluous to me.  I would just **roll it into `string_token_alloc()`**.

**Your only call to `string_token_alloc()` always passes `NULL` as the last argument**.  The function is `static`, so you can be sure that there will be no other calls. What's the point of that parameter, then?  It would be better to remove the parameter and instead just assign `NULL` to the member it is presently used to initialize.

**`string_token_alloc()` returns a null pointer on allocation failure, but `string_tokenize()` does not check for or properly handle that**.

**`string_tokenize()` does not need to pre-compute the input length**.  Whether it processes the input character by character or via `strcspn()`, it will know when it reaches the end of the input because it will observe the string terminator.  Precomputing the input length by calling `strlen()` is pure waste.

**Linked list algorithms are generally cleaner when supported by a dummy head node**.  That eliminates special case logic by allowing all real nodes to be treated as if they were internal nodes.  I would recommend that for the implementation of `string_tokenize()`.

**This conditional executes the same statement for both alternatives**:

> ```
>             if (token_length == 0) {
>                 previous_token_start_index = i + 1;
>             } else {
>                 previous_token_start_index = i + 1;
>             }
> ```

That statement should be executed unconditionally, instead.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need the inclusion of `stdlib.h` in `com_github_coderodde_thread_safe_strtok.h`. For the definition of `size_t`, `stddef.h` suffices.

---

`strncpy_s()` is a function from a part of the C standard that is called "Annex K" and that is optional.

According to the [C17 Standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf):

> An implementation that defines **STDC_LIB_EXT1** shall conform to the
> specifications in this annex.

which means that we require a check:

```
#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
 /* The implementation provides the optional functions. */
#else
 /* Do whatever */
#endif
```

But that alone doesn't suffice, it furthermore states:

> The functions, macros, and types declared or defined in K.3 and its
> subclauses are declared and defined by their respective headers if
> **STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1** is defined as a macro which expands to the integer constant 1 at the point in the source file where the
> appropriate header is first included.

which requires you to define `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1` to 1.

But then again, this annex is an optional extension, so you might be better off using something else.

Relevant [thread](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/libc-alpha/2007-05/msg00028.html) from 2007.

---

```
while (current_char_ptr != NULL) {
    if (*current_char_ptr == '\0') {
        return false;
    }

    if (*current_char_ptr == ch) {
        return true;
    }

    current_char_ptr++;
}
```

can be more simply expressed as:

```
while (current_char_ptr && *current_char_ptr) {
    if (*current_char_ptr == ch) {
        return true;
    }

    current_char_ptr++;
}
```

Or you could replace it with a call to [`strchr()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html). `character_belongs_to_delimiter_set()` would then simply be:

```
return strchr(delimiters, ch) != NULL;
```

---

`sizeof(char)` is always 1. You can safely replace it.

From the linked standard:

> When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned
> char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is
> 1.

---

Like standard `strtok()`, you may wish to use the `restrict` qualifier for both the parameters.

---

`sizeof` has two forms:

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
```

So you can write `sizeof *data` instead of `sizeof(*data)`, but that's just a minor style issue.