# Thread-safe strtok in C - version II

Tags: c, strings, parsing, library

After improving [Thread-safe strtok in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289582/thread-safe-strtok-in-c) according to [vnp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/289595/58360)'s and [Harith](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/289591/58360)'s nice comments, I ended up with this:

## Code

**`strtok_arr.h:`**

```
#ifndef COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_THREAD_SAFE_STRTOK_H
#define COM_GITHUB_CODERODDE_THREAD_SAFE_STRTOK_H

#include <stddef.h>

char** strtok_arr(const char* const text,
                  const char* const delimiters);

size_t strtok_arr_len(char** tokens);
void strtok_arr_free(char** tokens);

#endif
```

**`strtok_arr.c:`**

```
#include "strtok_arr.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct token_t {
    const char* token;
    struct token_t* p_next_string_token;
} token_t;

/********************************************************************
* Returns 'true' iff 'ch' is mentioned in the delimiter characters. *
********************************************************************/
static bool character_belongs_to_delimiter_set(
                char ch,
                const char* const delimiters) {

    return strchr(delimiters, ch) != NULL;
}

/***************************************************************************
* Frees the chain of tokens starting from 'p_token'. This function assumes *
* that the input 'p_token' is the head token.                              *
***************************************************************************/
static void free_tokens(token_t* p_token) {
    while (p_token != NULL) {
        token_t* p_next_token = p_token->p_next_string_token;
        free(p_token);
        p_token = p_next_token;
    }
}

/************************************************
* Creates a copy of a token residing in 'text'. *
************************************************/
static const char* token_copy(char* text, 
                              size_t token_offset,
                              size_t token_length) {

    /* + 1 in order to malloc the space for zero-terminator: */
    char* token_text = malloc(token_length + 1);

    if (token_text == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Terminate the token: */
    token_text[token_length] = '\0';

    /* Copy text[token_offset], ..., text[token_offset + token_length - 1]: */
    strncpy(token_text, 
            &text[token_offset], 
            token_length);

    return token_text;
}

char** strtok_arr(char* text, char* delimiters) {

    if (text == NULL || delimiters == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    token_t* p_head_token = NULL;
    token_t* p_tail_token = NULL;

    size_t text_length = strlen(text);
    size_t previous_token_start_index = 0;
    size_t number_of_tokens = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < text_length + 1; i++) {
        char ch = text[i];

        if (character_belongs_to_delimiter_set(ch, delimiters) || ch == '\0') {
            size_t token_length = i - previous_token_start_index;

            char* token_text = token_copy(text,
                                          previous_token_start_index, 
                                          token_length);

            if (token_text == NULL) {
                free_tokens(p_head_token);
                return NULL;
            }

            token_t* st = malloc(sizeof *st);

            if (st == NULL) {
                free(token_text);
                free_tokens(p_head_token);
                return NULL;
            }

            st->token = token_text;
            st->p_next_string_token = NULL;

            if (st == NULL) {
                free(token_text);
                free_tokens(p_head_token);
                return NULL;
            }

            if (p_head_token == NULL) {
                p_head_token = st;
                p_tail_token = st;
            } else {
                p_tail_token->p_next_string_token = st;
                p_tail_token = st;
            }

            previous_token_start_index = i + 1;
            number_of_tokens++;
        }
    }

    char** return_token_array = malloc((number_of_tokens + 1) * sizeof(char*));

    if (return_token_array == NULL) {
        free_tokens(p_head_token);
        return NULL;
    }

    return_token_array[number_of_tokens] = NULL;
    token_t* p_token = p_head_token;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_tokens; i++) {
        return_token_array[i] = p_token->token;
        p_token = p_token->p_next_string_token;
    }

    free_tokens(p_head_token);
    return return_token_array;
}

size_t strtok_arr_len(char** arr) {
    size_t number_of_tokens = 0;
    size_t i = 0;

    for (;; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == NULL) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    abort();
    return 0;
}

void strtok_arr_free(char** arr) {
    for (size_t i = 0; arr[i] != NULL; i++) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

## Critique request

How do you like it now? Especially, do I leak memory if `alloc` fails?

### Entire repository

All the stuff may be found in [GitHub](https://github.com/coderodde/ThreadSafeStrtok.c).

Answer (score 6):

### Reconsider `token_t`

This is currently a linear linked list of tokens, surprising given the name.  A strictly-evaluated linear linked list isn’t an efficient data structure, especially when you immediately copy the tokens into a dynamic array anyway.

Although this is a mistake I’ve often made myself, POSIX reserves identifiers ending in `_t`.  They could cause compatibility problems on Linux/UNIX in the future.

### Use String Slices

*K&R*-style null-terminated strings have a severe risk of buffer-overrun bugs. All the problems with thread-safety here are also caused by modifying the original string.

I suggest you define a data type like:

```c
typedef struct {
    const char* s;
    size_t n;
} CStringSlice;
```

A loop that tokenizes the entire string might then look like:

```c
    size_t bound = remaining.n; // Save this for the overflow check.
    CStringSlice token = next_toc( delimit, &remaining ); // This updates remaining.
    while (token.n > 0) {
// It is a logic error for a token to be longer than the string of which it is a substring.
        assert(token.n <= bound);
        do_stuff_with(token);
        bound = remaining.n;
        token = next_toc( delimit, &remaining );
    }
```

A slice can be passed to and returned from functions, allowing them to be chained.  Bundling the string’s length as part of it makes it much harder for the program to lose track and have a security bug.

Data that isn’t modified is safe to read from any number of threads.  You can now retrieve each token as a substring, without modifying the original string. Any number of reader threads can now extract tokens from the same input string in parallel, with no locking or waiting.  You do need to ensure that no thread modifies the original string while other threads hold references to it, and that it outlives any references to substrings within it.

### Avoid Ragged Arrays

It’s unfortunate that every C tutorial teaches `char** argv` early, because a pointer to an array of pointers to null-terminated strings is very rarely the data structure you want.

In most cases, your original string will outlive the references to tokens, so you can leave them as string slices for much better performance, and get thread safety too.  If you do need to make a deep copy of all the tokens, so you can destroy or overwrite the original buffer, I recommend the following algorithm instead:

1. Scan the string and save an array of slices representing each token.
2. Sum up the lengths of all slices. Add room for a terminating null `char` after each.
3. Make a single heap allocation of this total size.
4. Store the concatenation of all the tokens in that buffer, with a terminating `'\0'` after each.
5. Return an array of string slices into the new buffer.  These can now be used by any function that takes a string slice, a `char*` and length, or a null-terminated `char*`.
6. Have the delete function call `free()` on the start address of the first string slice of the array, then the array itself.

This minimizes calls to the heap, memory usage and cache misses when reading the data.

If you need deep copies of the individual tokens, you can create them with `strndup()`.  But you can eliminate that overhead whenever you don’t need it, so long as the slices don’t outlive the original string.  It’s especially important for multi-threaded code not to call `malloc()` or `free()` on each iteration, because that serializes the code and defeats the purpose of multi-threading.

### Eight-Bit Character Sets are Obsolete

The current implementation assumes either a character set from the 1990s, or ASCII, from the 1960s.  Any modern text-processing algorithm would need to support UTF-8.

Possible interfaces for this include:

- Taking a set of delimiters, or alternatively of token characters, as some kind of opaque type (such as a pointer to a hash set where the function can look up each character in constant time).
- Passing in a predicate function, for example one equivalent to `iswgraph()` from the standard library.  Each codepoint in the input string gets converted to `char32_t` and passed to this predicate function, to determine token boundaries. (For compatibility, avoid `wchar_t`, as this is UTF-16 on Windows.)

It’s simple to add backward compatibility for 8-bit character sets: ASCII or ISO Latin-1 only need to be widened from `unsigned char` to `char32_t`, and all other 8-bit encodings only need a small lookup table.  However, C lacks built-in sugar for a converting iterator.

Remember to normalize the strings you’re working with to NFD form, if you want to correctly implement Unicode canonical equivalence.